# How to get file list in a directory with webpack 5 at compile time

Tags: reactjs, webpack-5

The question is clear but I would like to give my use case for better understanding.

I'm creating a personal blog app and my blog posts will in **.mdx** format. These blog post .mdx files reside in a directory in the code base called **posts**. I can render any .mdx file in the following `BlogPost` component for each url like `/posts/post1`.

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

export const BlogPost = () => {
  let params = useParams()
  const Post = React.lazy(() => import(`../../posts/${params.postId}.mdx`))

  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Post />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And my file structure is like this:

```
/posts
--post1.mdx
/src
--/views
-----BlogPost.tsx
-----BlogList.tsx
```

So, whenever I want to add a new blog post I basically add a new **.mdx** file to the repository. However I don't want to edit any component. I mean, I don't want to have a variable that keeps list of the list of blog posts like following.

```
export const listOfBlogPosts = ["post1", "post2", ...]
```

Because it will need to be updated every time I add a new post. Instead I would like to get list of files dynamically in `BlogList` component.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import style from './BlogList.module.css'

export const BlogList = () => {
  const listOfBlogPosts = ['post1', 'post2'] // get somehow dynamically

  return (
    <div className={style}>
      {listOfBlogPosts.map((post) => {
        return <Link to={post}> {post}</Link>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

How can achieve this? Is there a logical problem with my approach(i.e keeping dynamic files in the repo)? Any suggestion or comment would be appreciated

Comment: What's the problem with 'ajax'

Comment: well, there isn't. I just don't have such a backend that publishes post API